# What is special about prn.csv?

Tags: python, windows, pandas

I am using Windows 7.

I am trying make a file called PRN.csv.  But get a "The specified device name is invalid" error.

I can make a file called PR.csv or PRN_.csv.

What is so special about PRN.csv?

N.B.  I discovered the problem while using Pandas / Python to save a dataframe to csv.  So it is relevant to this site.  Apologies for not making it clear at the beginning.

Comment: This seems relevant: http://superuser.com/questions/688145/cannot-create-con-csv-or-prn-csv-in-win7

Answer (score 4):

This is a holdover from the DOS days. There are a number of special file names that are reserved, such as PRN (referring to the default printer), CON (the console), COM1–COM4, etc.

This is purely a backwards-compatible effort in the upper layers of the system, though. If you use the right APIs, you can create such a file because the file system doesn't care at all:

[image: PRN.csv]

This was created in [Far Manager](http://farmanager.com/) which bypasses a few of such restrictions.